# renderDataTable with URL hyperlynks include server address before URL

Tags: r, shiny

I have the following code (simplified to show the problem):

```
#Defining UI with a file input selector
ui <- fluidPage(
            fluidRow(
                column(2,
                       fileInput("file",
                       label=HTML('<p style="color:black; font-size: 12pt"> File </p>')
                )
              )
          # Basic page
           basicPage(
           label=HTML('<p style="color:black; font-size: 14pt"> Results </p>'),
                dataTableOutput("table")
            )
# Define server 
server <- function(input, output) {

    
    res.table <- reactive({
        infile<-input$file
        
        if (is.null(infile)) return(NULL)
        
        data<-readRDS(infile$datapath)
        data<-data%>%
            mutate(URL=paste0('<a href=\\https://www.google.com',URL,'\\ target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary">','https://www.google.com',URL,'</a>'))
        

        return(data)
    })
   
    output$table <-renderDataTable({ 
        
        res.table()
        
        
        },escape=F,filter='top')
}
```

With this code, I obtain a clickable hyperlink. The problem is that before the URL the server direction is added: **http://123.0.0.1:4563/https://www.google.com**

How can I remove **http://123.0.0.1:4563** and why is it happening?

Thanks a lot for your help!